# Given a set of points forming a convex hull, is it possible to find a specific hyperplane?

Tags: combinatorics, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

I have a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and I can use some convex hull algorithm to find the convex hull of this set and the corresponding extreme points (vertices). My goal is to find the supporting hyperplane that contains a point $p$ where all elements are the same, i.e., $p=[p_1,p_2,...,p_n]$ and $p_1=p_2=...=p_n$. I can guarantee that if we create a ray of $p_1=p_2=...=p_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, this ray must pass the boundary of the convex hull.

I know there is a facet enumeration algorithm that we can find a H-representation given a V-representation of the convex hull. However, I just want to find the supporting hyperplane that contains the point $p$. Therefore, I am wondering if it is possible to just find such a hyperplane instead of finding all supporting hyperplanes of the convex hull.

**Edit**: The set of points $A$ is the convex hull of the extreme points of the unions over some hyperrectangles. Specifically, it can be described as follows:

$A=\text{Conv}(\text{extr}(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3))$ where $A_1,A_2,A_3$ are the collection of some points satisfying some conditions. Specifically, for any $i\in\{1,2,3\}$, $A_i=\{a_{i,1},...,a_{i,n}:0\leq a_{i,j}\leq c_i\,\forall\, j\in\{1,...,n\}\}$ where $c_i$ is a positive constant for each $i$ and $c_i\neq c_j$ for any $i\neq j$ is allowed.

**Edit**: I conjecture that the possible steps may be

1. Find the vertices that can form a hyperplane that contains $p$.
2. Use these vertices to create a hyperplane.

In the first step, we may investigate the amplitude of each coordinate of each vertex. In the second step, we may solve some linear algebra to find the hyperplane formed by the set found in the first step.

Comment: We may need more information about the original set of points you are choosing from. It is unclear to me why the line $\{(t,t,...,t) : t\in \mathbb{R}\}$ would always pass through your convex hull. Maybe if there is a way to demonstrate this for your specific set of points, then there is a way to find the supporting hyperplane, or face, that contains such a point $p$.

Comment: Similar counterexamples to that showing the lower bound of finding the convex hull can also be adapted to show that this problem is $O(n\log n)$ (and in worst case could have to check all but one facet of the hull) so naive facet enumeration seems suitable enough.

Comment: @Soundwave You mean that using facet enumeration would have the same time complexity with just finding the face that contains the point $p$?

Comment: @jerry Yes, and furthermore it seems there would be pathological collections such that facet enumeration is not only of the same complexity but optimal, given only the constraints you have.